# Glassfish V3.1 Invalid ejb jar it contains zero ejb

Tags: jboss, glassfish

I'm just about migrating from JBoss 6.1 to Glassfish 3.1 (don't ask why). The following occurs:

```
Invalid ejb jar [mmsUserMgmtAct-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar]: it contains zero ejb
...
Note: 
1. A valid ejb jar requires at least one session, entity (1.x/2.x style), or message- 
driven bean. 
2. EJB3+ entity beans (@Entity) are POJOs and please package them as library jar. 
3. If the jar file contains valid EJBs which are annotated with EJB component level 
annotations (@Stateless, @Stateful, @MessageDriven, @Singleton), please check server.log 
to see whether the annotations were processed properly.
```

As everything was running perfectly with Jboss I can swear there are EJBs within the jars. The only thing which might cause the error is the fact, that I splitted the interfaces (@Remote and @Local) plus the entities (@Entity) into a package xyzService.jar and the stateless bean (@Stateless, @Remote(XyzService.class)) into another archive named xyzServiceImpl.jar.

All packaging was generated by maven, so no issues with this. Maybe I should mention that I simply copied the things into autodeploy folder.

Any glues?

Thx in advance
El Subcomandante

Comment: OK, found the solution by myself ... @see http://www.coderanch.com/t/570995/EJB-JEE/java/deploy-EJB-jar-Glassfish